# how to modify a string live in a terminal using js

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

everyone. I am building a project named 'find your hat' in javaScript. This project needs you to modify a string live in a terminal without printing it again. I have found way to modify the string but it needs to print it again for showing a modification. Is there any way to modify a string in a terminal without printing it again?.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if what you describe applys to simple devbar-console, if so, just wrap it into a function and it shouldn´t print

```
test = "test" // prints "test"


function setTest(str){ test = str; }
setTest("test") // doesnt print "test" because function does not return anything, test is set though
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ***NO***

But you can do this.

```js
var count = 1;
var int = setInterval(()=>{
    console.clear();
    console.log("the number will be raised up");
    console.log(count);
    count++;
},100)
```

Here the code is clearing the console and inserting the updated value again.